# Reading Data by Chunking with HDF5 and Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, hdf5, pytables

When querying data in memory form a subset form CSV, I always do it this way:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', chunksize=10**3)

chunk1 = df.get_chunk()
chunk1 = chunk1[chunk1['Col1'] > someval]

for chunk in df:
    chunk1.append(chunk[chunk['Col1'] >someval])
```

I recently started playing around with HDF5, and am not able to do this because the TableIterator object does not have a `get_chunk()` method or accept `next()`.

```
df = pd.read_hdf('data.h5', chunksize=10**3)
df.get_chunk()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-xxxxxxxx> in <module>()
----> 1 df.get_chunk()

AttributeError: 'TableIterator' object has no attribute 'get_chunk'
```

Any ideas for a workaround? (I know that I can query from hdf5 on disk using pandas but for this purpose would like to try it this way)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It really does make sense to use HDF indexing in this case as it's much more efficient.

Here is a small demo:

generate test DataFrame (10M rows, 3 columns):

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10**7,(10**7,3)),columns=list('abc'))

In [2]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10000000 entries, 0 to 9999999
Data columns (total 3 columns):
a    int32
b    int32
c    int32
dtypes: int32(3)
memory usage: 114.4 MB

In [3]: df.shape
Out[3]: (10000000, 3)
```

save DF to HDF file. Make sure column `a` is indexed (`data_columns=['a',...]` or `data_columns=True` - to index **all** columns)

```
fn = r'c:/tmp/test.h5'
store = pd.HDFStore(fn)
store.append('test', df, data_columns=['a'])
store.close()
del df
```

test reading from HDF file:

```
fn = r'c:/tmp/test.h5'
chunksize = 10**6
someval = 100
```

**Timing:**

read HDF in chunks and concatenate filtered chunks into resulting DF

```
In [18]: %%timeit
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame()
    ...: for chunk in pd.read_hdf(fn, 'test', chunksize=chunksize):
    ...:     df = pd.concat([df, chunk.ix[chunk.a < someval]], ignore_index=True)
    ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 2min 22s per loop
```

read HDF in chunks (conditionally - filtering data by HDF index) and concatenate chunks into resulting DF:

```
In [19]: %%timeit
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame()
    ...: for chunk in pd.read_hdf(fn, 'test', chunksize=chunksize, where='a < someval'):
    ...:     df = pd.concat([df, chunk], ignore_index=True)
    ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 79.1 ms per loop
```

**Conclusion:** searching HDF by index (using `where=<terms>`) is **1795** times faster compared to reading everything and filtering in memory:

```
In [20]: (2*60+22)*1000/79.1
Out[20]: 1795.19595448799
```

Comment: How did you make this work? When I try the code above I am getting errors like: `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 100000), indices imply (1, 1551440685)` - I tried every possible combination of chunksize, iterator, etc, and it is failing all the time...

Comment: @DejanLekic, did you try to execute the code from my answer? what is your Pandas version?

Comment: pandas 0.20.1, tables 3.4.2 ... Getting this weird error... If I omit chunksize it runs out of memory trying to load everything into memory... If you could give me your exact versions that would be great so I can pin my requirements to those and try again... BTW, I can't use where. I need to load ALL records, because I am trying to convert HDF5 files to Parquet table-by-table...

Comment: @DejanLekic, just tested it against Pandas: 0.20.1, tables: 3.2.2, numpy: 1.12.1

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
chunk1 = pd.concat([chunk[chunk['Col1'] > someval] for chunk in df])
```